# Easiest way to have proper HTTPS with a custom domain on GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, https

My website runs on Google App Engine and is so far accessed via HTTP. I would like to change that to HTTPS. However, using the appspot.com domain instead of my own domain is not an option for me.

Is there any straightforward way to do so without having to deal with manually managing (updating etc.) certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, when you build apps on App Engine, SSL is on by default —  you no longer need to worry about it or spend time managing it. We’ve made using HTTPS simple: map a domain to your app, prove ownership, and App Engine automatically provisions an SSL certificate and renews it whenever necessary, at no additional cost. Purchasing and generating certificates, dealing with and securing keys, managing your SSL cipher suites and worrying about renewal dates —  those are all a thing of the past.
>
> To get started with App Engine managed SSL certificates, simply head to the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains) and add a new domain. Once the domain is mapped and your DNS records are up to date, you’ll see the SSL certificate appear in the domains list. And that’s it. Managed certificates is now the default behavior —  no further steps are required!

https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-managed-SSL-for-Google-App-Engine.html

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to buy and upload your own certificate. The process is quite straightforward, though.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not find it straightforward. I spent hours with problems like [How to set the intermediate certificates on GAE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746643/)

Comment: @ whoever downvoted this answer: please, be polite - look at the date of an answer before downvoting. This was the correct answer back then.

Comment: Downvotes are locked until you edit your answer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/idea-behind-your-vote-is-now-locked-in-unless-this-answer-is-edited
BTW: maybe you also want to remove that "straightforward" on that occasion ;-)